# Angular 5 - Best practice for avoiding degradation in the application performance

Tags: javascript, performance, angular5

I have a scenario where there is application data being retrieved from server and logging data( which is being pushed to database for end to end trace ability which includes info like operation name , inputs , outputs and data) being sent to the centralized server. We need that the application performance does not decrease by sending the logging data along with the application data being retrieved from the server using **same browser** . So is there any way we can make the **efficient use of browser** by sending the logging data to server as and when browser has less load using Angular 5 ?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways of doing this. In fact, there are libraries built for just this kind of thing. I suggest searching on "asynchronous logging library javascript".

Comment: Hi Mike Thanks for the response . Can  you please provide some useful links for the same . Also i have one more question , if I want to access local storage as part of logging mechanism in separate JavaScript thread , is there any suitable way for that ?

Comment: Sure: https://www.google.com/?q=asynchronous+logging+library+javascript... You're asking a lot of questions without doing a lot of research. [Please do some research yourself, rather than asking volunteers to do it for you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: Hi Mike , I already did a lot of research on this part like using Web worker where we can not access the local storage ( to be more specific , via the window object , window.localStorage) . Also , i did think to use Indexed DB , but performance wise it is not the appropriate . After all this , i reached out to the community , not simply asked the question . Thanks for the response !!!